# Scoring runs when a no ball is caught

Tags: rules, cricket

**When a ball is batted in the air and then caught, but it was called a no ball (so they can't be dismissed caught), will the batting team score any regular runs of the ball they completed (and can they potentially be run out)?**

Two similar situations happened in two different IPL matches, but was seemingly treated differently.

In ball 19.5 of the second innings of the [32nd IPL 2015 match between Mumbai Indians and Rajasthan Royals](http://www.espncricinfo.com/indian-premier-league-2015/engine/match/829769.html?innings=2;view=commentary), there was a run-out after a no ball was caught (an additional run was also scored, the run-out happened when they attempted a second).

> Vinay Kumar to Binny, (no ball) 1 run, OUT, another full toss, in the air again and he's caught at long-on. This was definitely over the waist, and is called no-ball. Pollard doesn't realise that and throws the ball late, which makes Southee comes back for the second. But his throw is accurate and Vinay takes the bails off casually, catching Southee's bat short despite the dive. A no ball, a run, a run out

In ball 19.4 of the first innings of the [19th IPL 2015 match between Sunrisers Hyderabad and Kolkata Knight Riders](http://www.espncricinfo.com/indian-premier-league-2015/engine/match/829743.html?innings=1;view=commentary), the ball was caught, but replays showed that it was above waist height and it was called a no ball, and in addition a run was scored. This was shown on televsion and CricBuzz and CricInfo.

But then in the innings break the score was adjusted, and as CricInfo says "The target is 177, not 178. The run taken on the no-ball for height in the last over won't be taken into account as the catch was taken".

> UT Yadav to Rahul, 1 no ball, high full toss swung high over midwicket, long on runs in to his right to take it, but replays show that is just above waist height, and it is a no-ball

IPL actually [tweeted](https://twitter.com/IPL/status/590854542272499713) about this.

Was one of these two situations treated wrong, or am I misinterpreting or missing some extra information which makes the two situations different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Law on no-ball is available [here](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-24-no-ball/).

Section 14 says "Any runs completed by the batsmen or any boundary allowance shall be credited to the striker if the ball has been struck by the bat; otherwise they shall also be scored as No ball extras." Therefore, they should have been awarded the completed runs.

They can be run out, according to the run out law ([here](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-38-run-out/)), where section says he cannot be run out "if No ball has been called
and he is out of his ground not attempting a run
and the wicket is fairly put down by the wicket-keeper without the intervention of another fielder.". However, in the cases above the batsman was attempting a run and was therefore fair game.

Comment: "they should have been awarded the completed runs". This would match my reading of the rules - which is why the IPL tweet is particularly confusing, as you'd expect a professional league to know the laws of the game. I find it hard to believe they were wrong and nobody cared, but I don't have a better explanation.

Comment: keep in mind the second example, the no-ball was not called during normal play. The catch was taken so the play stops. You cannot make runs off that. However since it was later deemed a no-ball it would be unfair to the fielding team since they thought the play was stopped... so no batting runs were added